# JButton and a boolean

Tags: swing, boolean, jbutton

Ok so I looked around already for a couple of hours and didn't really find any usefull answers. So anyway, I'm currently studying some programing and I can't seem to find my mistake. I've used eclipse to find my mistake but it doesn't show any errors.

So anyway, I want to make this button go on and off and to do so I made a boolean called turnOn and set it's starting value to 'false'

I added a JButton and linked it with a 'ActionListener', but when I run my program and press on my button it won't turn on.

It basicly needs to show the drawLine when I press on my button and back off. I'm sure it's probably a starter error, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Code:

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MijnProject extends JPanel{

private JTextField tekstvak1;
private JLabel label1;
private JButton knop;
private boolean turnOn=false;

    public MijnProject(){

        label1 = new JLabel("Aantal zeepjes");
        tekstvak1 = new JTextField(10);
        knop = new JButton("Aan/Uit");
        knop.addActionListener(new StartknopHandler());
        add (label1);
        add (tekstvak1);
        add (knop);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(20, 100, 5, 400);

        if(turnOn==true){
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawLine(55, 125, 35, 500);
        }
    }

    class StartknopHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(turnOn==false){
                turnOn = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: where do you repaint your component after the button is pressed?

Comment: Yeah that is it, I also showed this to some of my older friends none of them saw it. Now i can continue.

Answer (score 1):

You should use JToggleButton for this purpose.